# Creating array consisting of struct values

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I create correct struct array without using jagged array? I have tried -

```
student[] newarray = new student[]{student_info,student2_info};
Console.WriteLine(newarray[0]);
```

But i get "project name.student" in console

```
public struct student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
class H
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student student_info = new student();
        student_info.Name = "Mike";
        student_info.Last_Name = "Johnson";
        student_info.Address = "Baker str. 84/4a";
        student_info.City = "New LM";
        student_info.Country = "Paris";

        student student2_info = new student();
        student student3_info = new student();
        student student4_info = new student();
        student student5_info = new student();

        string[] my_array1 = { student_info.Name,  student_info.Last_Name,   student_info.Address,  student_info.City,   student_info.Country };
        string[] my_array2 = { student2_info.Name, student2_info.Last_Name,  student2_info.Address, student2_info.City,  student2_info.Country };
        string[] my_array3 = { student3_info.Name, student3_info.Last_Name,  student3_info.Address, student3_info.City,  student3_info.Country };
        string[] my_array4 = { student4_info.Name, student4_info.Last_Name,  student4_info.Address, student4_info.City,  student4_info.Country };
        string[] my_array5 = { student5_info.Name, student5_info.Last_Name,  student5_info.Address, student5_info.City,  student5_info.Country };

        string[][] list = new string[][] { my_array1, my_array2, my_array3, my_array4, my_array5 };
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++) 
            { 
                //  Console.WriteLine(list[x][y]);
            }

            student[] newarray = new student[]{student_info,student2_info};
            Console.WriteLine(newarray[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get 'project name.student' is that this is the default output of the ToString() method of your struct.
You need to add an override of ToString() to your Student struct that will return whatever you want to be written to the console.

Another option is to send to the Console.WriteLine a property of your struct, such as `Console.WriteLine(newarray[0].Name);` (as suggested by [fix_likes_coding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633957/fix-likes-coding) and [Hellfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166163/hellfire) in the other answers to this question
)

You can use any of these options, to my personal taste the override of ToString seems more elegant.

Comment: Elegant depending on what the intent is, if you just want to output the name then the first is more elegant, if you wanted to output "Name LastName (Address)" overridding ToString is so much better than concatenation or string.format ;)

Comment: @Hellfire: Yes and no. It's generally more elegant because you don't have to specify the property in the Console.WriteLine. It's encapsulated in the `ToString()`. However, if the common use is to show full name, and in another case you wish to show only the first name, of course the elegant way would be to return the full name using `ToString()` and write `Console.WriteLine(newarray[0].Name);`

Answer (score 2):

What are you hoping to output to the console?

What you are seeing is the full type name of the object due to the default object.ToString implementation. You need to pick the property to output to the console, not the object if you want to see something.

Change this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(newarray[0]);
```

To this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(newarray[0].Name);
```

and your output will be the students name.

Answer (score 2):

`ProjectName.student` is the type of the struct. The default `ToString()` of an object or struct will print its type.
Now depending on what properties of the student you want to write to output you can do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Students name: {0}", newarray[0].Name));
```